# MATLAB: Interpolation that involve a matrix

Tags: matlab

I try to interpolate a relation that involve a matrix but while I am setting up it I encounter an error
`Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.`
For example, let

```
A = [1 2;3 4];
I = [1 0;0 1];
ft = linspace(0, 5, 25);
f = A.*ft + I.*ft.^2; %f is a matrix
t = [0:0.1:1];
f = interp1(ft, f, t);
```

I encounter the error of dimension in the line of `f = A.*ft + I.*ft.^2;`. I surely know how to get around this using for loop. But I do not want to do a for loop. Also, in this case I cannot do interpolation. How to get around with this problem?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to interpolate? Between [1 2] and [3 4] with 25 points? or do you want a 25*25 map wit hthe corner being [1 2 3 4]?

Comment: I try to interpolate it with time. `ft = linspace(0, 5, 25)` is the times what I know for the values of `f`. I try to learn what `f` is for `t = [0:0.1:1];`.

Comment: What size matrix do you expect `f` to be?

Comment: @Steve 2 by 2 as `A`. It is the "`A`" at each timestep.

Comment: That special function/operator would be like this:  I have `[1 2 3]` and I have `A`.  `[1 2 3]` operates on `A` gives a higher dimensional list `[A 2*A 3*A]`.

Comment: If you have the answer you needed, please upvote them and accept one, in order to remove this post from the 'unanswered' queue. Otherwise, you can still edit it to get an answer.

Comment: @kww, `kron([1 2 3],A)` yields `[A 2.*A 3.*A]` as you request in your comment, which is a single (wide) matrix. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.*`, which is scalar multiplying, so you get an error because you try do do an element-wise operation on matrices that have different size (2*2 for `A` *v* 1*25 for `ft`).

I guess what you really want is to set up side by side (0*A, 0.04*A, 0.08*A, ...,  0.96*A, 1*A). If so, you should consider using a simple `for` loop and fill `ft` step by step.

[This function](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) may also help you if you want at all cost avoid the loop, let me know how that worked out

Comment: Thanks. I think it is quite a common thing for us to do something like `(0*A, 0.04*A, 0.08*A, ..., 0.96*A, 1*A)`. Instead of using for-loop, why isn't there some convenient function to achieve this? I have `[1 2 3]` and I have `A`. I want a higher dimensional list of `[A 2*A 3*A]` .

Comment: I have no idea. Did my answer help you anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

the error is because dimensions of `A` is `2x2` while dimensions of `ft` is   `1x25`. you cannot perform element-wise multiply `.*` on two matrices with different dimension.

Comment: I know. But not exactly elementwise, i just want scalar multiplication. I intend to multiple each time scalar with the matrix. 0*A, 0.2083*A, 0.4167*A, .... I can do it in for-loop for sure. But then I cannot perform interpolation.

Comment: `repmat(A, [1, size(ft)]).*repmat(permute(ft,[1,3,2]),[size(A),1])` will give you `2x2x25` where each slice `i` is `ft[i]*A`